# Why does the variable (line 6) get a space in white? (Nivel: Beginner Workflow Runestone)

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

```
 1. '''  x = 1    '''      # initialize x print(x)  
 2. '''  x = x + 1    # update x    '''
 3. '''  print(x) for n in range(4):    '''
 4. '''  n= n+1    '''
 5. '''  print("nmap -n -Pe 10.0.2 ",n)    ''' # Why the variable get a space in white ? 
 6. '''  print("nmap -n -PE 10.0.2.",n)    ''' Why this line is equal than previous line?
 7. '''  print("Range imprime :", x,"el número exacto") #con respecto al anterior lista    '''
```

Why does the variable (line 6) get a space in white? (Nivel: Beginner Workflow Runestone)

***Thanks All!***

Answer (score 0):

You get a white space for variable for line 6 because the default separator for print is ' '.

> Here's the function definition for print():
>
> > print(object(s), separator=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)

Let me describe what the function definition says:

- object(s): Any object, and as many as you like. Will be converted to string before printed
- sep='separator'  Optional. Specify how to separate the objects, if there is more than one.

> Default is ' '(this is why we get a white space)

- end='end'    Optional. Specify what to print at the end. Default is '\n' (line feed)
- file     Optional. An object with a write method. Default is sys.stdout
- flush    Optional. A Boolean, specifying if the output is flushed (True) or buffered (False). Default is False
  If you want to add any-other separator like '*', then:

  `print('Hello','world!',sep='*')`

Which will output: Hello*world!

As for your other question: Why this line is equal than previous line?
Answer: It is same because it is being passed as an object param and hence will be treated as a simple string, if you want to print variables then I'll suggest you use str.format().
Demo for str.format():

```
import math as m
print(str.format('Value of PI: {0}, Value of e:{1}',m.pi,m.e))
```

Output: Value of PI: 3.141592653589793, Value of e: 2.718281828459045

**Hope this helps you. Cheers!**